# Send Data From html5 app to database by ajax and php

Tags: ajax

i have start a new application html5 and i need to send from that app the info user_points to the database i have the code that send a fixed amount points.
But Now I need to change the php code to receive ajax request to update is points on database From My html5 app.
what i can change to this php code to receive the ajax variable user_points and store in database?

```html
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
// Retrieve data from database 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
//$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET points=`points`+5 WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION['user']."'");
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']);
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET user_points = user_points +'user_points' WHERE user_id = " . $_SESSION['user']);
// close MySQL connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

assume your php script is called run.php

and assume run.php is called via ajax like this [http://yourserver/run.php?user_points=10&userid=12&sessiontan=8162836zqwizß182402834080oio](http://yourserver/run.php?user_points=10&userid=12&sessiontan=8162836zqwiz%C3%9F182402834080oio)

your script run.php would need to look like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_GET['userid']) and isset($_GET['user_points'] and isset($_GET['sessionpin']))) {
  $res=mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM sessiontans WHERE user_id=x".dechex($_GET['userid'])" and sessiontan=x".dechex($_GET['sessiontan']));
  if($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET user_points = user_points + x".dechex($_GET['user_points'])." WHERE user_id = x" . dechex($_GET['userid']));
  }
}
// close MySQL connection 
 mysql_close();

?>
```

As far as I am aware the session context is not available in ajax called scripts. So security wise that needs to 'simulated' via sessiontans or similar mechanisms. I assumed now, you would follow a sessiontan approach. A session tan be created in your app as soon as the user logs and is via time stamps only valid for a tiny time frame (a couple of minutes/hours). A sessiontan would need to be different from session-IDs.

I personally would add more sophisticated checks on the user-points to make sure that the those are not tricked... Anyway that is more on the 'game logic' side and would require a lot more insight on what this is all about.

Also in terms of performance tuning both statements could become part of a multi query: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.multi-query.php
Again this is advanced programming tactics and superexceeds the scope of your question.